# Child window in Electron does not always show on top

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to create two windows from the main process. The second window should always be shown on top of the first window. On the  [Electron website](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#parent-and-child-windows) I have read that I have to create a parent and a child window to do this.
This is my code:

```
let win;
let child;

function createWindow(){
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 1024, height: 768, show: false});

  child = new BrowserWindow({parent: win});
  child.show();

  win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    win.show()
  })
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null;
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

When I start the program it creates two windows but the child window is not always on top. When I close the parent window (win) both windows are closed.
How do I make the child window always be shown on top?
I'm using Fedora 24 with Gnome.

Comment: Have you tried to use this method after child-win init?
`child.setAlwaysOnTop(true);`

Comment: @tehcpu Thanks for your response. I tried adding child.setAlwaysOnTop(true); and it works.

Comment: fine. You are welcome ;)

Comment: @tehcpu add this as an answer.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar, great idea, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `child.setAlwaysOnTop(true);` method after child-win init.

Comment: It will always on top of all applications, how if we just want to on the top of the electron application itself?

Comment: @JasinYip you can use `new BrowserWindow({ parent: top })`

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is you show the child window directly after launch app and you  show the parent window after ready-to-show so the child show first and parent show ontop of child.

To make your child show ontop of parent window you need to do this :

```
win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    win.show()
    child.show()
})
```

and remove `child.show()` on top

Answer (score 0):

You can use the focus.

```
 win.on('focus',function(){
        if(child!=null && child.isVisible()){
            child.focus()
        }
    });
```

It set the child window on top of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do always on top window

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
stopScreenShareWin = new remote.BrowserWindow({ 
                    width: 400, 
                    height: 40, 
                    show:true, 
                    alwaysOnTop:true, 
                    frame: false,
                    titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
                    visibleOnAllWorkspaces:true , 
                    webPreferences: {
                        nodeIntegration: true
                    }
                });
    stopScreenShareWin.loadFile('calls/screenshare-overlay.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

By your question, I suppose that u need a in windows's dialog, but not a new sub window

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30400758)